# React-grid layout. dynamic update of grid item values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-grid-layout

Im new in react and  I would like to try to use the react-grid-layout.

I would like to understand if it is possible to display the 'x' value of the layout on the item so that I can see the x coordinate change with the movement of the mouse. Obviously each item must have its own  'x' coordinate value .. but I just can't figure out how to do it. I'm sure there is an easy way but I can't see it.

here my code

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-grid-layout-componet-isy1w?file=/src/App.js

here the function: el.x it is not updated with the layout change

```
createElement(el) {
const removeStyle = {
  position: "absolute",
  right: "2px",
  top: 0,
  cursor: "pointer"
};
const i = el.i;
/* const index=i.slice(1);
console.log(index) */

console.log();
return (
  <div className="wrapper" key={i} data-grid={el}>
    <p>
      <span className="text">
        {el.i} + **{el.x}**
      </span>
    </p>
    <p>
      <span className="text"></span>
    </p>
    <span
      className="remove"
      style={removeStyle}
      onClick={this.onRemoveItem.bind(this, i)}
    >
      x
    </span>
  </div>
);
```

}

thank you very much

Comment: Can you please include the full code of your component? 
Note that if the variable `x` is not part of the **state**, React won't re-render the component for no reason. React wouldn't know that `x` has changed and so it wouldn't update the rendered component.

Comment: Hi Charis, thanks for the quick answer. You are right. I solved it by updating the react-grid-layout layout array  directly. here the code: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-grid-layout-componet-isy1w?file=/src/App.js&resolutionWidth=702&resolutionHeight=675

Answer (score 0):

You should go for creating `AppContainer` and then `CardContainers` With their respective functionality nested-in. and styling them with external library...  I would recommend using `styled-components`, Very easy to use and much better to design app layout instead of creating from scratch. As I'm using in my project as well. I hope this will help you out. git repo https://github.com/faisalnazik/Django-REST-framework-React.JS-Typescript.git

Comment: Thank you Faisal. Now I start studying styled-components, it seems very interesting.